# Creating php links via username to edit data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

I'm new to PHP, so any advice would be fantastic.

I have created a user panel, so when a user logs into my site they can see all their information.

What am I asking help for?
When I log in as the administrator I want to have a piece of PHP will allows all users to be listed with a link next to their name.
so the list may look like:

```
terry123 >> link here >>
barry123 >> link here >>
```

From the links they will be redirected to my `edit.php` which will show all the information of the user via its `username` or `ID` using a `_GET` method so I can edit it.

CODE HERE ---

```
 <?php
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("jonathon_admin1", $con);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin"); 
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query); 


if ($UserAdmin == "admin") {

    echo "your logged in as admin, Running this Code:<br />";
    echo "<br />";

    // TEST HERE


  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<a href="edit.php? id=".$row['id'] . ">".$row['UserName']."</a>"";

  }



  //
} // end if statement



mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Do you want us to build this for you or are there elements you don't understand?

Comment: @user1074406 As you are selecting `username` from database select addition column `id` and echo link with `<a href="edit.php?id=$id">link</a>`

Comment: @user1074406: what is the specific question other than `canihaztehcodez`?

Comment: If you can write a user control panel, you already know how to write an admin control panel...

Comment: @user1074406 I believe that would be the answer i was looking for! Thank you very much, I did not need the code, just a heads up in which direction i should go. That should do be perfect Thanks!!

Comment: Yes i think this is going to work! Thanks guys who helped, as to the others I wasnt just asking for the code but simply help. Thanks Pradeep for taking a moment to help. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the `users` table (or whatever name you've put it under), use `mysql_fetch_array` to make it a usable array, put the array through a `while` loop and echo each row's contents as an HTML list.

Something like this:

```
echo "<ul>";
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
while($row = $rows){
    echo "<li><a href=\"edit.php?id=".$row['id']."\">".$row['username']."</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly the type of help i needed!First class help mate cheers!

Comment: So this will link the username and Id together when being re-directed to edit.php.

Comment: On the page where you put the code, it will generate a list of your users. The link will take you to `edit.php?id=[user id]`, and the link text will be the username.

Comment: Hi There, tried your method using: echo "<li><a href="edit.php?id=".$row['id'].">".$row['username']."</a></li>"; but cannot get it to work, says in browser: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/jonathon/public_html/testing/test.php on line 152 -- SEE ABOVE FOR CURRENT CODE

Comment: @user1074406: See my edit, that was my mistake. You have to escape the quotes before `edit.php`.

Comment: THANKS!! This works but something still wrong with my code, do you by any chance have Skype to catch a chat when your online? email me: leggtech@gmail.com if you do :) I could learn alot from you, regards jon

Comment: AWW Unfortunately it seems to spam the same user all the way down the list (which is never ending) and uses the same ID, think it seems to get stuck in a loop! email me if you have skype thanks!